# Xcode 9.1 cant start the Iphone simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode9.1

I just installed Xcode 9.1,before Xcode 9.1,when I click the "Play" button on top,the Iphone simulator start automatically.But after install Xcode 9.1,the iPhone simulator didnt start,no error,no phone appear on screen,only Xcode show build success.

Can somebody tell me how to solve this?So I can test the project on Iphone simulator.

**Edit**

After looking for a question in So,I able to start the simulator,by doing

> Click on Target next to Play Button -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Change
>   the **Executable** to "My Project"

The iphone simulator can start,but it give me this error

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Show your project(Xcode) screenshot.

Comment: Check the target name if correct it’s near the play button

Comment: did you try to force quit xcode (Command + Q). After that restart your Mac and retry. Happened to me once this fixed it.

Comment: @zombie target name is correct,it same with my project name

Comment: @MohammadBashirSidani I just quit Xcode,restart the mac,still no Iphone simulator show up..Yesterday still have Iphone shown up,but the iphone cant start also,always "Timed out when waiting Iphone simulator to start"

Comment: @ImadAli what I need to show??

Comment: remove the simulators and add it again.

Comment: @ken Edit your question & Add screenshot of the Xcode project (when opened).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a issue with iPhone simulator.You can see this issue in fastlane's git hub page as well. Happens more often when you are using command line tools.

**Solution :** Simply tap command + space opens hot search, type simulator and hit enter,

[image]

your simulator might not load and show an error thats fine. Now go to actions select simulator and say Reset Content and Settings.

[image]

Now go back to your Xcode and re run the code. Hope this resolves the issue

Comment: Hey sir,I just edit my question..can you please get a quick look again??

Comment: @ken : looks like something messed up in your simulator. Try resetting it, usually resetting solves most of the problems. If it doesn't lemme know

Comment: @ken : yeah mate

Comment: hey bro is very weird,my simulator dont have "Reset Content.." option here,can u take a look? https://imgur.com/a/Rr9Tc in this image..

Comment: @ken : Quit your simulator from doc, press command + space it will open hot search, type in Simulator and hit enter. Now go to top bar and look for reset content as shown in answer above :)

Comment: @ken : Please consider accepting the answer if it helped

Comment: @ken : Thank u :)